# how to pass value to an action in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build an event calendar. In this I have written a gateDate function that returns the date of respective clicked field from the calendar I have created. I want to pass this date to index action please help me.

```
function getDate() {

                $('.cal_daybox').on('click', function () {
                    var timestamp = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
                    var day = new Date(timestamp);
                    alert("You clicked " + day.toDateString());


                });
            }
```

Thank You.

Comment: if you wanna be a bad boy just go: `window.location= '/Home/Index?date='+day.toDateString();`

Answer (score 1):

Put that date in hiddenfield and make a function which redirect user to index action.

eg.

```
function goToIndex() {
    var _date = $('#hiddenfield').val();
    document.href = '/Home/Index/?date=' + _date;
}
```

Comment: why not make it a whole form? why exactly do you put it into a field and then parse manually, when you can parse manually in the first place??

Comment: yeah.. it depends on developer. i just gave him an idea of doing what he wanted to do